# "in Cambridge Dictionary" vs. "on Cambridge Dictionary"

Tags: prepositions

[From an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/250263/109190)

> There are two meanings of "action" related **in Cambridge Dictionary** ...

When talking about an website, we usually use the preposition "on".

When talking about a dictionary, we usually use the preposition "in".

"Cambridge Dictionary" in my quoted sentence is combination of both. In this particular situation, should I use "on" or "in"?

Comment: I think you should use either "in the Cambridge Dictionary" or "on the Cambridge Dictionary website", whichever way you want to put it.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Thank you. I guess I could also use '**from** the Cambridge Dictionary', right?

Comment: Yes, that works too.